# Where do I set idle_in_transaction_session_timeout in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I want to close idle connection in postgresql and want to set idle_in_transaction_session_timeout. I log into postgresql and when entering show idle_in_transaction_session_timeout at prompt get the following error message:

> [database]=> show idle_in_transaction_session_timeout;

and get the following error message:

> ERROR:  unrecognized configuration parameter
>   "idle_in_transaction_session_timeout"

If i enter [database]=> SET SESSION idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 3000; get the following error message:

> ERROR:  unrecognized configuration parameter
>   "idle_in_transaction_session_timeout"

Where do consult and set this variable in posrgresql? Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

From my install of Postgresql on a BSD server. The option you're looking for is declared in `postgresql.conf` in the folder: `var/db/postgresql/data96`

as:

```
#idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 0        # in milliseconds, 0 is disabled
```

Its location on *your* install is dependent upon the OS, and version of Postgresql you're using. In my case `9.6`.

Short, and *direct* answer: `postgresql.conf`. :)

Comment: I checked postgresql.conf in the server and I don't have a line with #idle_in_transaction_session_timeout=0. I am running version 9.2.24. If I add the line idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 5000 to postgresql.conf then Postgresql reports an error when I try to restart it.

Comment: As indicated in my answer. This *may* well be a "version specific" option. I'm not sure which version that option was introduced. But it is at *least* available in 9.6. So it will at least be available in 9.6, maybe sooner. But surely later. :)

Comment: Thank you. Will upgrade and test.